# Perl data structures - looping an array of hashes inside a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

I need a data structure to keep metadata about a field in a database, which I'm going to access to write dynamic SQL.

I'm using a hash to store things like the name, maybe data type, etc. And most importantly, an array of hashes containing information about the values I want to query out of the field, and the name I want to alias them with.

When I try to access elements of that array, I get:

```
Global symbol "%elem" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 18.
```

It sounds like maybe it's having trouble registering the fact that the loop variable representing the array elements is a hash, not a scalar. If I try:

```
foreach my %elem
```

then I get:

```
Missing $ on loop variable at test.pl line 17 (#1)
```

So far I can't find the relevant Perl documentation that addresses this.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use warnings; 
use strict; 
use diagnostics; 
use POSIX 'strftime'; 

my %struct = (
        #"field" = "foobar",
        "values" => [ 
                  {value => "Y", name => "FOO"} 
                , {value => "N", name => "BAR"} 
        ] 
); 

foreach my $elem (@{$struct->{'values'}}) { 
        print $elem->{'value'}; 
}
```

I expect the program to print "YN" to the console.

UPDATE, as someone pointed out I needed to use `%hash->{'ref'}` in the loop addressing. I added it. Now, I get a notification saying that using a hash as a reference is deprecated (?) but it is printing to the console now!

Comment: $elem is hashref (there is no %elem hash in your code), thus `print $elem->{'value'}`

Comment: Yep - can't believe that's all it was. I was following this, which didn't use it. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch09_02.htm - but it must have been for something different.

Comment: No need to change `$struct{'values'}` as this is actual hash `%struct`, not hashref as $elem. Please check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was misunderstanding, thank you for finding it for me.

Comment: You shouldn't fix your question to include solutions that people offer as it makes nonsense of them. Add some modified code to your existing question if you want to demonstrate that solutions *don't* work. You now have answers to your original question *and* your updated one so they are in conflict. Remember that Stack Overflow is a *knowledge base* and not a forum

Answer (score 1):

When I tried running your code, I got a different error than you reported:

```
Global symbol "$struct" requires explicit package name
```

This is because you've defined a hash `%struct`, not a hashref `$struct`, so you don't need to dereference it.  Thus, I changed the line

```
foreach my $elem (@{$struct->{'values'}}) {
```

to

```
foreach my $elem (@{$struct{'values'}}) {
```

(note no `->` to dereference) and it ran perfectly, no errors or warnings, and emitted the output

```
YN
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`%struct` is a hash, not a hash reference. Therefore, `$struct->{'values'}` is not the correct way to access the `values` key.

```
for my $elem (@{$struct{values}}) {
    print "$elem->{value}\n";
}
```